# Bootstrap 4 navbar tabs not activating tab content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm in the process of learning a little bootstrap and I found a tutorial for navbar with 3.3.5 and could get it working fine.

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#superman">Superman</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#batman">Batman</a></li>

  <!-- Dropdown menu item -->
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Flash
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

      <!-- Disable a tab -->
      <li class="disabled"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#flash">The Flash</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#kidflash">Kid Flash</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="superman" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <p>Superman is a fictional superhero appearing in American comic books published by DC Comics. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="batman" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>Batman is a fictional superhero appearing in American comic books published by DC Comics. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="flash" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>The Flash is a fictional superhero appearing in American comic books published by DC Comics. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="kidflash" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>Kid Flash is a fictional superhero appearing in American comic books published by DC Comics. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I realized that 4 was the most recent version I figured it'd be best to learn 4.  I can get the navbar to work properly with 4 but I can find no documentation on how to actually change the content being displayed when the different tabs are pressed.  The code I have so far is below.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Augma Home</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#menu">Menu</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#colors">Colors</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I looking for the equivalent of the tab-content from 3.3.5.  I'm looking for some youtube tutorials now but if anyone has anyone that they feel is particularly good please feel free to share.  Also I apologize if this is a really basic question I'm a backend guy so being unfamiliar with the jargon for this front end stuff has made search for this particular issue rather frustrating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use list groups (`list-group`) or tabs (`nav-tabs`) in Bootstrap 4.

Click the "run code snippet" button below to see an example with tabs:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">home tab</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">profile tab</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">contact tab</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Click the "run code snippet" button below to see a list group example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">home home home</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">profile profile profile</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">messages messages messages</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">settings settings settings</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tabs work similar in Bootstrap 3 and 4, and `data-toggle="tab"` is still used. Instead of using the `in` class to set the active tab-pane, the `show` class is now used in Bootstrap 4.

If you were unable to activate the tab content from the `navbar`, the reason is most likely the same 
[as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920131/bootstrap-4-navbar-to-navigate-tabs/48927185#48927185). 
The **`nav`** class must be included in the `navbar-nav` in order for the tab navigation to work.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/7pjdI2heSU

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Augma Home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#superman">Superman</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#batman">Batman</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#flash">Flash</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#kidflash">Kid Flash</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using bootstrap.js version 4.5.2 and the navbar-nav is not yet working.
I think the issue related to the version of bootstrap.css used in the solution.
while comparing to bootstrap.css previous version they have a slight change in the `in` and `nav` class.

the `in` class changed to `show` in the latest version of bootstrap.css

I resolved this issue int the following way

1. updated the `.show` class in bootstrap.css into `.show { opacity: 1 !important; display: block !important; }`

2.by changing the HTML or js file by adding the `in` or `active` class

```
$('.classofthe-tab').on("click", function () {
    $('.tab-pane').addClass('in');
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```